# How do I use an object for setting variable in JSP for loop?

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop

I need to loop through the list, but foreach loop is not acceptable as I want to start from the second element.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
<c:out value="${item.name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

I tried to use standard java code in "<% %>" but I cannot come up how to set it up right. My syntax is just wrong, I need something like this

```
<% for (int i = 1; i < ${items.size()}; i++) { %>
    <c:out value="${item.name}"/>
<%} %>
```

But, obviously, the code above is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSTL `varStatus` property. It might help you.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="loop">
  <c:if test="${loop.index != 0}">
    <c:out value="${item.name}"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```